# MongoDB $sort using aggregate is really slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am creating a new field during aggregation in order to sort result by relevancy. Unfortunately the $sort method just slow down my request execution. Can you explain me how to make it faster ?

Here my code :

```
MyClass.aggregate([
        {"$match":   query}
        ,{
            "$project" : Object.assign({
                //
                //  Build relevancy score
                //
                "relevancyScore": {blablabla...}
             }, otherFields)
        }
        ,{"$sort":{"relevancyScore":-1}} // This line slow down the request
        ,{"$skip":   currentPage * pageSize}
        ,{"$limit":  pageSize}
    ])
    .exec(function (err, res) {
        if (err) return console.log("error", err);
        resolve(res);
    });
```

If I $sort by '_id' it is really fast because _id field is indexed. Unfortunately my relevancyScore field is created in flight...

Thank you ! :D

Comment: Is there a field in your docs where sorting on it would always sort in the same order as the computed relevancyScore?

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: Sounds like you should consider persisting relevancyScore to the document rather than calculating it as part of the query.

Comment: But if my score depends on a user input ?

Comment: There's no getting around the fact that for a sort to have good performance on a large collection, it needs to be supported by an index.

Comment: Okay, then I'll review my db design! Thank you